# Trying to recover information from an encrypted HDD

Tags: linux, data-recovery, pop-os

My primary HDD is encrypted has failed or is failing.  I am trying to recover any data from it.  After getting a new drive with Pop_os! installed, I have been able to unlock it and can see the partition in /dev/mapper.

I have attempted:

```
sudo mount /dev/mapper/bad_drive /mnt/test_drive/
```

recieved:

```
mount: /mnt/test_drive: can't read superblock on /dev/mapper/bad_drive.
```

tried:

```
sudo fsck -c -v /dev/mapper/bad_drive
```

and recieved:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
fsck.ext2: Input/output error while trying to open /dev/mapper/bad_drive

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

I also attempted:

```
ls -l /dev/mapper/
```

Recieved:

```
total 0
crw------- 1 root root 10, 236 Oct  7 08:19 control
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Oct  7 08:19 cryptswap -> ../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Oct  9 07:23 bad_drive -> ../dm-1
```

and lastly tried:

```
sudo pvdisplay /dev/dm-1
```

recieved:

```
Error reading device /dev/mapper/bad_drive at 0 length 512.
  Error reading device /dev/mapper/bad_drive at 0 length 4096.
  Error reading device /dev/sdc at 0 length 512.
  Error reading device /dev/sdc at 0 length 4096.
  Error reading device /dev/sdc1 at 0 length 4096.
  Error reading device /dev/sdc2 at 0 length 4096.
  Error reading device /dev/sdc3 at 0 length 4096.
  Error reading device /dev/sdc4 at 0 length 4096.
  Cannot use /dev/dm-1: device has a signature
```

The Disks program that comes with Pop_Os! recognizes the drive, says it is likely to fail soon, allows me to unlock the encrypted partition, format the partition (presumably I haven't tried due to not wanting to lose data but the option is not grayed out) but I cannot mount the encrypted partition.

I've tried to use GParted but this program will not find the drive.

Can anyone help me get the partition mounted or repaired so that I can recover the data?

Comment: If the drive is misbehaving, first step should be `ddrescue` to a working drive. Can't do anything with bad hardware. Do NOT fsck without backup/snapshot. Also keep an eye on `dmesg` for specific error message, sometimes it's benign (cable issues). Also check `smartctl -a`.